# Sending a tweet using Authlogic-OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, twitter, authlogic-oauth

I'm building a Rails application which uses Authlogic for authentication, which I've now set-up to run using the OAuth extension, meaning a user can be created by signing in from Twitter.

This stores their OAuth token and OAuth secret, meaning they're accessible, but I was wondering how I would actually go about sending a tweet using these?

So, with the users credentials, how do I format the POST request, and how do I do this in the controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a gem like such: http://twitter.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Thanks, installed the gem - looks pretty good. Can't get Authlogic-OAuth and it to play nicely though (re: access tokens).

Comment: Not to worry - sorted it now. Thanks for linking me to that gem.